# Characterization of the isomorphic semidirect products

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

Let $A$ and $G$ be two finite abelian groups and let $\alpha$, $\beta:G\rightarrow{\rm Aut}(A)$. Suppose that $\alpha (G)$ and $\beta (G)$ are conjugate subgroups of ${\rm Aut}(A)$. Are the semidirect products $A\rtimes _{\alpha }G$ and $A\rtimes _{\beta }G$ isomorphic?

I know that this is true for a finite cyclic group $G$ but I don't what to do if $G$ is a finite non-cyclic Abelian group. I think the answer is usually no, so I will be thankful if someone provides me a counterexample.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, they are isomorphic and "Abelian" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

If we assume only that the images of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugate in $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$, then the answer is no.  Let $A = C_3$ and $G = C_4 \times C_2$, and consider two surjective homomorphisms $\alpha, \beta:  G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A) \cong C_2$ with kernels isomorphic to $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ respectively.  Then each of the two resulting semidirect products has a unique Sylow 3-subgroup $A$, whose centralizer is $A \times \ker \alpha$ or $A \times \ker \beta$ respectively.  These subgroups are non-isomorphic, so the semidirect products are as well.  Concretely:
$$A \rtimes_{\alpha} G \cong C_4 \times (C_3 \rtimes C_2) \cong C_4 \times S_3, \text{ while} $$
$$A \rtimes_{\beta} G \cong C_2 \times (C_3 \rtimes C_4) \cong C_2 \times \mathrm{Dic}_{12},$$
where both semidirect products above are given by the unique nontrivial actions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, I'm interested with the case when  G is not a 2-group. Thank you again.

Comment: @NohaRaghit You can tweak this construction and even make everything odd-order if you like.  For example, take $A = C_7$ and $G = C_9 \times C_3$, with $G$ acting on $A$ via $G \overset{(*)}{\twoheadrightarrow} C_3 \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(A) \cong C_6$, where the marked surjection is the quotient by a subgroup isomorphic to $C_9$ resp. $C_3 \times C_3$.  The same argument shows that the resulting semidirect products are non-isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you.  We get the same if we take $A = C_7$ and $G = C_6\times C_2$,  and consider two homomorphisms $\alpha, \beta:  G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A) $ with kernels isomorphic to $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$ respectively.

Comment: @NohaRaghit Not quite--$C_6 \times C_2$ doesn't have a subgroup isomorphic to $C_4$.  But replace $C_6$ with $C_{12}$ and it works (with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given by...?)

Answer (score 1):

That is not the answer to the question. Here is a condition under which the named groups are isomorphic.

If $f\in\operatorname{Aut} A$ is chosen such that for any $x\in G$ and $a\in A$ holds
$$
f^{-1}\alpha(x)f(a)=\beta(x)(a)
$$
and multiplications in the group $A\rtimes_\alpha G$ are given by the rule
$$
(a,x)(b,y)=(a+\alpha(x)(b),xy)
$$
(we use the additive notation of the operation in $A$),
then the mapping $(a,x)\to (f(a),y)$ is an isomorphism of the group $A\rtimes_\alpha G$ to the group $A\rtimes_\beta G$.

Comment: Thank you. But   the conjugacy of   
  $ \alpha(G)  $ and $ \beta(G)$   does not necessery give us the existence of $f\in\operatorname{Aut}(A)$ such that 
$
f^{-1}\alpha(x)f=\beta(x)
$.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have corrected my answer.